# Python - Recursion vs. Iteration in a Linked List implementation

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

What's the difference in the following code? Links refer to Linked List objects. The .first() and .rest() attributes return the first and remaining values respectively. In accordance to StackOverFlow policies and my class's policies, I want to mention that this is not an assignment--it was an optional assignment that was long due, and I am revisiting it trying out iteration vs. recursion to study for my upcoming examination.

Here are some doctests.

```
>>> s = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3)))
>>> s.rest.rest.rest = s
>>> has_cycle(s)
True
>>> t = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3)))
>>> has_cycle(t)
False
>>> u = Link(2, Link(2, Link(2)))
>>> has_cycle(u)
False
```

**Here is my recursive solution for the function def has_cycle(link):**

```
existing = []
def cycle(link):
    nonlocal existing
    if link is not Link.empty:
        if link in existing:
            return True
        existing.append(link)
        cycle(link.rest)
cycle(link)
return False
```

**Alternatively**

```
existing = []
while link is not Link.empty:
    if link in existing:
        return True
    existing.append(link)
    link = link.rest
return False
```

Thank you. I should mention that the iterative version works, the recursive version does not.

Link List Class:

```
class Link:
    """A linked list.

    >>> s = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3)))
    >>> s.first
    1
    >>> s.rest
    Link(2, Link(3))
    """
    empty = ()

    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.rest is Link.empty:
            return 'Link({})'.format(self.first)
        else:
            return 'Link({}, {})'.format(self.first, repr(self.rest))
```

Comment: Is the indentation correct in your actual code?

Comment: Is the indentation I posted incorrect? Forgive me, I don't quite see what you're referring to.

Comment: I assume `Link.empty` yields `True` or `False`; if so, your condition `if link is not Link.empty` will never hold true, because `link` is not `boolean`.  Just change that condition to `if not Link.empty` and you're done.

Comment: In that case, the iterative solution should never work? But it does. I don't think that's it.

Comment: Well, then show us your `Link` class :) Uh -- and you should `return cycle(link.rest)` (return its result, not just call it).

Comment: @jbndlr I've edited the original post to include the Linked List class.

Answer (score 1):

```
existing = []
def cycle(link):
    nonlocal existing
    if link is not Link.empty:
        if link in existing:
            return True
        existing.append(link)
        cycle(link.rest)
    else:
         return False

res = cycle(link)
#print res
```

Try this out as your recursive version....

Comment: That worked. Ugh, that was simple. Thank you for your help. I needed to add another return to cycle(link). I missed how the returns work in higher order functions. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your returns are missing or inappropriate. When descending into recursion, you need to return its respective result. Also, you need to return something in case your emtpy-condition does not hold true:

```
existing = []
def cycle(link):
    nonlocal existing
    if link is not Link.empty:
        if link in existing:
            return True
        existing.append(link)
        return cycle(link.rest) # Return result of recursive call
    else:
        return False # Return false if link is empty
print(cycle(link))
```

Comment: You were right!! Thank you so much for your time. I need to watch my returns in higher order functions and recursion. Thank you